# Django ORM, group_by is grouping by all values

Tags: python, django, orm, group-by

When I am trying to use

```
products = products.annotate(count_prices=Count('prices'))
```

unfortunatelly it is using all select parameters :(

How can I force to group by by one field? I have for example a lot of

```
products.extra(select = {'purchase_price': """ ...
```

And it is adding it to group by. Any ideas?

Comment: I've answered your question, but for future notice, please try to provide more details, e.g. what is `products`, what field you want to group on, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by field "x":

```
products.values("x").annotate(count_prices=Count('prices')).order_by()
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I cannot access then another fields. I cannot include easly more because it is really big part of code and I didnt dig into it yet (it's not mine). I was thinking there is easy way to say group_by('field'). Using values() I cannot access other fields.